# c++ <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x1>

Tags: c++

I really don't understand why my code is having this problem

First I'm creating two pointers to char

```
char* finWord;
char* ignoredWord;
```

Then I pass them as parametres to other functions

```
lowerCase(line.substr(0, endWord), ignoredWord);
toNormalWord(ignoredWord, finWord);
```

But when I run the program it throws me a Segmentation fault, and the problem is that finWord address is allways 0x1

Here is where the problem occur

```
void toNormalWord (string src, char* des) 
{
    char c;
    des[sizeof(src) + 1];
    int position = 0; 

    if (isThere)
    {
        des[position] = c; //Here the gdb show me the following error 0x1 <error: 
                           // Cannot access memory at address 0x1>
        position++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think `des [sizeof(src) + 1];` is doing what you think it is doing

Comment: In addition to create the pointers, you should make the pointers point somewhere. Currently, they are just garbage or, which is not much better, 0. That is, they point not into a valid address, but into Nirvana, and that's where your process goes when using them.

Comment: your variables seem uninitialized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
des[sizeof(src) + 1];
```

does nothing. But even if it did something it wouldn't do what you wanted it to do. First, you're just referencing a single byte in memory somewhere and not doing anything with it. And secondly, `sizeof(src)` is not the length of the string you get passed in... it's the size of the `std::string` class, which is a constant independent of the length of the actual string.

What you mean to do is actually create a new array:

```
des = new char[src.size() + 1];
```

But this will just leak memory, since `des` is a local variable. What you probably want to do is:

```
char* toNormalWord(const std::string& src) 
{
    char* des = new char[src.size() + 1];
    // stuff
    return des;
}
```

Or even better, not use `char*` to begin with:

```
std::string toNormalWord(const std::string& src)
{
    std::string des = src;
    // stuff
    return des;
}
```