# Memory leaking with memory allocation

Tags: c++, dynamic, memory-leaks

[c++ <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x1>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726695/c-error-cannot-access-memory-at-address-0x1)
​
I have an additional question about this question.
The answerer said that the first one

```cpp
des = new char[src.size() + 1];
```

will cause memory leaking since des is a local variable so he suggested another method right after.

```cpp
char* toNormalWord(const std::string& src)
{
   char* des = new char[src.size() + 1];
   // stuff
   return des;
}
```

But I can't understand why the local variable will cause memory leaking and what is the difference between the first one and the second one.
Isn’t the second one also using `des` as a local variable in the function?
I thought the difference was just that the function receives `des` as a parameter or just creates themselves.
I think I don't know something important but I don't know what that is...

Comment: Where is your call to `delete []` the memory?  It is the lack of using `delete []` at some point in the code that causes the memory leak.  Take the advice of the answer given at the link -- use `std::string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand the meaning of the sentence fragment *"will just leak memory, since `des` is a local variable"*, one must understand the context. What was not said explicitly is that the value of the local variable was in no way copied elsewhere.

If the value is lost, then allocation is leaked.

> what is the difference between the first one and the second one.

When the value assigned here: `des = new char[src.size() + 1];` is not communicated to the outside of the function, the allocation will unconditionally leak at the end of the function.

When the value is returned, it can potentially be deleted later, thereby avoiding the leak.

> Isn’t the second one also using des as a local variable in the function?

Yes. The difference is in whether its value is returned or not.

Answer (score 0):

first, des is local variable but it is pointer variable and you allocate (src.size() + 1) size memory so it allocated in heap memory in your process.

check this web site

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/

Answer (score 0):

eerorika [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55291568/1938348) is correct, but can be expanded.

Then memory is allocated locally then this function responsibility is to deallocate it.
If you return it then you push this responsibility on someone else and this is dangerous. You will have same problem like in your function but in other place:

```
char* toNormalWord(const std::string& src);

void processString(const std::string& src)
{
    char* des = toNormalWord(src);
    /* ... */
    if (c == '\n') throw new std::exception("invalid character!"); //memory leak of `des`!
    /* ... */
    return; //memory leak of `des`!
}
```

Now your memory is now local to other function and it should be free there.

Probably best way to avoid all this is use `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> toNormalWord(const std::string& src)
{
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> des(new char[src.size() + 1]);
    /* ... */
    return des;
}

void processString(const std::string& src)
{
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> des = toNormalWord(src);
    /* ... */
    if (c == '\n') throw new std::exception("invalid character!"); //no memory leak!
    /* ... */
    return; //no memory leak!
}
```

with this compiler will always remember to free this memory.

In this specific case you can use `std::string` [as suggested by barry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27726737/1938348). In some cases I even used `std::vecotr` for strings. All this depend on what usage of this "memory" is.
`std::string` is best when you need do a lot of string operations like concatenation.